# Mysql Trigger, Copy All Rows From One Table Into Another Table

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have three tables.

table **prefix**. here i have default prefixes

```
id     code    indx    price
```

table **pricelist**. this table has pid, joins to the maintable id.

```
id     code    name    price  pid
```

table **cars**

```
id   name   country   bla    bla
```

Is there any chance to make trigger in mysql, after insert into table **cars**, copy all records from prefix into pricelist. When I create new car, I want to copy default infos from prefix to pricelist.

I saw some documentation in stack, but some of them could not help, some of them was about other solutions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER `copy_default` AFTER INSERT ON cars
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
   insert into pricelist (id, code, name, price)
   select NEW.id, code, indx, price
   from prefix;
END;
//
delimiter ;
```

Something like that. The exact `insert` statement depends on what columns you want to copy.

Comment: is there any way to write VALUES (NEW.id) inside this trigger?